# What is Shopify's product.price variable exactly?

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify's Liquid templates, the product.price variable is supposed to return the "price of the product" (as [documented here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-price)).

However, if a create a product with 2 variants, set variant A's price to $11.00 and variant B's price to $12.00, what will product.price return?

Answer (score 2):

`{{ product.price }}` is the same as `{{ product.min_price }}`. So you'd get 1100.

If you want to look at the prices of each variant you can do that too, e.g. `{{ product.variants[0].price }}`.

Comment: Great to get confirmation of this. Should be in the docs though :)